# vmc targetting faild with my own server

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, vmc

i'm trying to install cloudfoundry on my own server , i used this steps [here](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/08/howto-install-cloudfoundry-server-paas.html)

,the installation complete successfully and all service run without any problem.

but when i use `vmc target api.vcap.me` the targtting process failed !

when is check the vcap access log this line appeared when i try to connect :
`168.144.196.107 - [14/Dec/2012:16:38:44 -0500] "GET /info HTTP/1.1" 404 214 "-" "Ruby" 41.9.133.520 response_time:0.001`

any help please ?

Note : i edit my hosts file to accept api.vcap.me

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you followed is out-dated. I would like to recommend you follow the official document here on GitHub: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap. That should give you a very detailed and updated steps to build your own PAAS server up.